# Laravel and AWS S3 file upload and download failed

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.7

Im using Laravel 5.7 and AWS S3 storage. Due to prevent memory usage problem. Ive change it to stream upload and download. But i cant get the download function working. Ive change the php.ini required file to the preferred max value. The files size what im trying to download is just 2mb+ and already give me this error. uploading file size seems no problem for big files. (6-8Mb tested)

```
$fileName = 'images/file/'.$elearning->file;
if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

return response()->stream(function() use ($fileName) {
    $stream = Storage::disk('s3')->readStream($fileName);
    fpassthru($stream);
    if (is_resource($stream)) fclose($stream);

}, 200, [
    'Cache-Control'         => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Content-Type'          =>  $elearning->type, 
    'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($elearning->title) . '"',
    'Pragma'                => 'public',
]);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: browser site seems stop process it. "This site can’t be reached, ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"